# Name / Context for strange "one-sided continuity" property

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

I stumbled upon the following property, which I need for a certain proof.

Let $f : M \to \mathbb R$, where $M$ is a metric space.

> For every $x\in M$ there exists an open set $U\subseteq M$ with $x\in
>  \partial U$ (boundary of $U$), such that for all $y\in U$, $f(y) < f(x)$.

In my example I have $M := \mathbb R^d \times [0,T]$ and $f(x,t) = T-t$ and I require this property in the context of a function $g(x,t,\eta) = \lceil \frac{T-t}{\eta} \rceil - 1$.

What's the above property called and / or what is it a consequence of?

Comment: @bof I hope I fixed it. The goal is to consider nets in $U$ that converge to $x$.

Comment: I don't know anything nontrivial. Trivially, your property is a consequence of "$f$ is upper semicontinuous and has no local minima."

Comment: @bof That's a good tip, since my $f$ needed to be upper-semicontinuous anyway. You can post this as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function with your property has no local minima. For upper semicontinuous functions the converse holds: An upper semicontinuous function $f:M\to\mathbb R$ with no local minima has your property. For, given a point $x\in M$, the set $U=\{y\in M:f(y)\lt f(x)\}$ is open by upper semicontinuity, and $x\in\partial U$ because $f$ does not have a local minimum at $x$.